# Making a request to an ActiveStorage resource fails occasionally when used alongside Apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, apartment-gem

#### Use-case

We're using Apartment gem alongside ActiveStorage.
In our Amazon S3 server, we have created a bucket for every tenant in our application.
Since ActiveStorage can hold only one bucket globally, we're switching the ActiveStorage bucket for every request.

#### The problem

When a request from one tenant is being served and a new request from another tenant comes in, the bucket held by ActiveStorage gets switched to that of the new tenant.
Now if the first tenant request is trying to access a resource in ActiveStorage, it results in a failure since request is being made with incorrect bucket name

[Pictorial representation attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6Xw.jpg)

#### Current workaround

A fallback mechanism to check if the generated ActiveStorage URL is valid. If it's invalid, change the bucket name held by ActiveStorage to that of the current tenant and make a new request

Is there a better way of solving this problem?